# How to get image URL from Wordpress post trough API request in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, fetch-api

My last post here helped me a lot, so now I have a list of suitcases in my app, that I got from my posts (which are my products). This is a screenshot of the current app:

[image: this is a screenshot of the current app]

Now for the picture, which is a gold suitcase that I imported with a simple URI, I also want to get the image from my individual posts so that every title has his own unique picture. For example: the EVO S black has to be a black suitcase, the EVO L needs to be a gold suitcase. This is how my WordPress post looks like, it's very simple:

[image: wordpress post with suitcase]

This is how my JSON file - the part of the image - looks in Postman:

```json
"content": {
            "rendered": "\n<figure class=\"wp-block-image size-medium productfoto\" id=\"productfoto\"><img decoding=\"async\" loading=\"lazy\" width=\"200\" height=\"300\" src=\"https://evivermeeren.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/goud-medium-4-300-hard-4-1-200x300.webp\" alt=\"productfoto\" class=\"wp-image-2316\" title=\"productfoto\" srcset=\"https://evivermeeren.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/goud-medium-4-300-hard-4-1-200x300.webp 200w, https://evivermeeren.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/elementor/thumbs/goud-medium-4-300-hard-4-1-pyt9usybvdz52sk2fmq1xdh2o41yey1c3o3sjd2c0c.webp 500w, https://evivermeeren.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/goud-medium-4-300-hard-4-1.webp 600w\" sizes=\"(max-width: 200px) 100vw, 200px\" /></figure>\n",
            "protected": false
        },
```

I gave my picture a class, an attribute name and so on, all of which are 'productfoto'.

This is the current code in React Native, with the fetch for the titles and here you can see that I import the picture myself with a URI instead of the fetch:

```js
const AllSuitcasesScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
 
  const [suitcases, setSuitcases] = useState([]);
 
  const getSuitcases = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://evivermeeren.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=59", {
 
        }
      )
      const json = await response.json();
      console.log(json);
      setSuitcases(json);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
 
  }
 
  useEffect(() => {
    getSuitcases();
  }, []);
 
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>

          <View style={styles.flexbox2}>
            <Text style={styles.products}>Onze koffers</Text>
            <View style={styles.shoppingcart}>
              <Image
                  style={styles.icon}
                  source={{uri: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1413/1413908.png'}}
                />
              <Text style={styles.number}>0</Text>
            </View>
          </View>

        <View style={styles.list}>
        <FlatList
        data={suitcases}
 
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <SuitcaseItem
          title={item.title.rendered}
          imageUri={{uri: 'https://evivermeeren.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/goud-medium-4-300-hard-4-1.webp'}}
          />

        )}
      />
      </View>
    </View >
  );
}
```

Does anybody know how I can take the image URL from the API fetch and put this into my flatlist so that every post (block) has his own title with the right picture above it? Maybe it's simple, but I can't figure it out.

This is a part of my JSON, I thought it should be something like: `URI=item.yoast_head_json.og_image.url` but that doesn't work.

```json
{
        "id": 2484,
        "date": "2022-12-17T15:02:56",
        "date_gmt": "2022-12-17T15:02:56",
        "guid": {
            "rendered": "https://evivermeeren.com/?p=2484"
        },
        "modified": "2022-12-18T10:39:37",
        "modified_gmt": "2022-12-18T10:39:37",
        "slug": "zwart-groot-hard-249euro",
        "status": "publish",
        "type": "post",
        "link": "https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/",
        "title": {
            "rendered": "Evo L Black"
        },
        "content": {
            "rendered": "\n<p id=\"desc\">Een grote koffer in een zwarte kleur, gemaakt van hard materiaal. De prijs van deze koffer is €249.</p>\n",
            "protected": false
        },
        "excerpt": {
            "rendered": "<p>Een grote koffer in een zwarte kleur, gemaakt van hard materiaal. De prijs van deze koffer is €249.</p>\n",
            "protected": false
        },
        "author": 1,
        "featured_media": 2229,
        "comment_status": "closed",
        "ping_status": "closed",
        "sticky": false,
        "template": "",
        "format": "standard",
        "meta": [],
        "categories": [
            59
        ],
        "tags": [],
        "yoast_head": "<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast SEO plugin v19.12 - https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/ -->\n<title>Evo L Black - Evi Vermeêren</title>\n<meta name=\"robots\" content=\"index, follow, max-snippet:-1, max-image-preview:large, max-video-preview:-1\" />\n<link rel=\"canonical\" href=\"https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/\" />\n<meta property=\"og:locale\" content=\"nl_NL\" />\n<meta property=\"og:type\" content=\"article\" />\n<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"Evo L Black - Evi Vermeêren\" />\n<meta property=\"og:description\" content=\"Een grote koffer in een zwarte kleur, gemaakt van hard materiaal. De prijs van deze koffer is €249.\" />\n<meta property=\"og:url\" content=\"https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/\" />\n<meta property=\"og:site_name\" content=\"Evi Vermeêren\" />\n<meta property=\"article:published_time\" content=\"2022-12-17T15:02:56+00:00\" />\n<meta property=\"article:modified_time\" content=\"2022-12-18T10:39:37+00:00\" />\n<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"https://evivermeeren.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/zwart-klein-4-300-hard-4-e1670410664142.webp\" />\n\t<meta property=\"og:image:width\" content=\"200\" />\n\t<meta property=\"og:image:height\" content=\"300\" />\n\t<meta property=\"og:image:type\" content=\"image/webp\" />\n<meta name=\"author\" content=\"evivermeeren\" />\n<meta name=\"twitter:card\" content=\"summary_large_image\" />\n<meta name=\"twitter:label1\" content=\"Geschreven door\" />\n\t<meta name=\"twitter:data1\" content=\"evivermeeren\" />\n\t<meta name=\"twitter:label2\" content=\"Verwachte leestijd\" />\n\t<meta name=\"twitter:data2\" content=\"1 minuut\" />\n<script type=\"application/ld+json\" class=\"yoast-schema-graph\">{\"@context\":\"https://schema.org\",\"@graph\":[{\"@type\":\"Article\",\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/#article\",\"isPartOf\":{\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/\"},\"author\":{\"name\":\"evivermeeren\",\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/#/schema/person/d74bd513920b6e8cf81e3693e10c9de0\"},\"headline\":\"Evo L Black\",\"datePublished\":\"2022-12-17T15:02:56+00:00\",\"dateModified\":\"2022-12-18T10:39:37+00:00\",\"mainEntityOfPage\":{\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/\"},\"wordCount\":20,\"publisher\":{\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/#/schema/person/d74bd513920b6e8cf81e3693e10c9de0\"},\"articleSection\":[\"Koffers\"],\"inLanguage\":\"nl\"},{\"@type\":\"WebPage\",\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/\",\"url\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/\",\"name\":\"Evo L Black - Evi Vermeêren\",\"isPartOf\":{\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/#website\"},\"datePublished\":\"2022-12-17T15:02:56+00:00\",\"dateModified\":\"2022-12-18T10:39:37+00:00\",\"breadcrumb\":{\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/#breadcrumb\"},\"inLanguage\":\"nl\",\"potentialAction\":[{\"@type\":\"ReadAction\",\"target\":[\"https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/\"]}]},{\"@type\":\"BreadcrumbList\",\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/#breadcrumb\",\"itemListElement\":[{\"@type\":\"ListItem\",\"position\":1,\"name\":\"Home\",\"item\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/\"},{\"@type\":\"ListItem\",\"position\":2,\"name\":\"Evo L Black\"}]},{\"@type\":\"WebSite\",\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/#website\",\"url\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/\",\"name\":\"Evi Vermeêren\",\"description\":\"\",\"publisher\":{\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/#/schema/person/d74bd513920b6e8cf81e3693e10c9de0\"},\"potentialAction\":[{\"@type\":\"SearchAction\",\"target\":{\"@type\":\"EntryPoint\",\"urlTemplate\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/?s={search_term_string}\"},\"query-input\":\"required name=search_term_string\"}],\"inLanguage\":\"nl\"},{\"@type\":[\"Person\",\"Organization\"],\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/#/schema/person/d74bd513920b6e8cf81e3693e10c9de0\",\"name\":\"evivermeeren\",\"image\":{\"@type\":\"ImageObject\",\"inLanguage\":\"nl\",\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/#/schema/person/image/\",\"url\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/logo.png\",\"contentUrl\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/logo.png\",\"width\":661,\"height\":824,\"caption\":\"evivermeeren\"},\"logo\":{\"@id\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/#/schema/person/image/\"},\"sameAs\":[\"https://evivermeeren.com\"],\"url\":\"https://evivermeeren.com/author/evivermeeren/\"}]}</script>\n<!-- / Yoast SEO plugin. -->",
        "yoast_head_json": {
            "title": "Evo L Black - Evi Vermeêren",
            "robots": {
                "index": "index",
                "follow": "follow",
                "max-snippet": "max-snippet:-1",
                "max-image-preview": "max-image-preview:large",
                "max-video-preview": "max-video-preview:-1"
            },
            "canonical": "https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/",
            "og_locale": "nl_NL",
            "og_type": "article",
            "og_title": "Evo L Black - Evi Vermeêren",
            "og_description": "Een grote koffer in een zwarte kleur, gemaakt van hard materiaal. De prijs van deze koffer is €249.",
            "og_url": "https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/",
            "og_site_name": "Evi Vermeêren",
            "article_published_time": "2022-12-17T15:02:56+00:00",
            "article_modified_time": "2022-12-18T10:39:37+00:00",
            "og_image": [
                {
                    "width": 200,
                    "height": 300,
                    "url": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/zwart-klein-4-300-hard-4-e1670410664142.webp",
                    "type": "image/webp"
                }
            ],
            "author": "evivermeeren",
            "twitter_card": "summary_large_image",
            "twitter_misc": {
                "Geschreven door": "evivermeeren",
                "Verwachte leestijd": "1 minuut"
            },
            "schema": {
                "@context": "https://schema.org",
                "@graph": [
                    {
                        "@type": "Article",
                        "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/#article",
                        "isPartOf": {
                            "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/"
                        },
                        "author": {
                            "name": "evivermeeren",
                            "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/#/schema/person/d74bd513920b6e8cf81e3693e10c9de0"
                        },
                        "headline": "Evo L Black",
                        "datePublished": "2022-12-17T15:02:56+00:00",
                        "dateModified": "2022-12-18T10:39:37+00:00",
                        "mainEntityOfPage": {
                            "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/"
                        },
                        "wordCount": 20,
                        "publisher": {
                            "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/#/schema/person/d74bd513920b6e8cf81e3693e10c9de0"
                        },
                        "articleSection": [
                            "Koffers"
                        ],
                        "inLanguage": "nl"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "WebPage",
                        "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/",
                        "url": "https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/",
                        "name": "Evo L Black - Evi Vermeêren",
                        "isPartOf": {
                            "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/#website"
                        },
                        "datePublished": "2022-12-17T15:02:56+00:00",
                        "dateModified": "2022-12-18T10:39:37+00:00",
                        "breadcrumb": {
                            "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/#breadcrumb"
                        },
                        "inLanguage": "nl",
                        "potentialAction": [
                            {
                                "@type": "ReadAction",
                                "target": [
                                    "https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
                        "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/zwart-groot-hard-249euro/koffers/#breadcrumb",
                        "itemListElement": [
                            {
                                "@type": "ListItem",
                                "position": 1,
                                "name": "Home",
                                "item": "https://evivermeeren.com/"
                            },
                            {
                                "@type": "ListItem",
                                "position": 2,
                                "name": "Evo L Black"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": "WebSite",
                        "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/#website",
                        "url": "https://evivermeeren.com/",
                        "name": "Evi Vermeêren",
                        "description": "",
                        "publisher": {
                            "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/#/schema/person/d74bd513920b6e8cf81e3693e10c9de0"
                        },
                        "potentialAction": [
                            {
                                "@type": "SearchAction",
                                "target": {
                                    "@type": "EntryPoint",
                                    "urlTemplate": "https://evivermeeren.com/?s={search_term_string}"
                                },
                                "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
                            }
                        ],
                        "inLanguage": "nl"
                    },
                    {
                        "@type": [
                            "Person",
                            "Organization"
                        ],
                        "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/#/schema/person/d74bd513920b6e8cf81e3693e10c9de0",
                        "name": "evivermeeren",
                        "image": {
                            "@type": "ImageObject",
                            "inLanguage": "nl",
                            "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/#/schema/person/image/",
                            "url": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/logo.png",
                            "contentUrl": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/logo.png",
                            "width": 661,
                            "height": 824,
                            "caption": "evivermeeren"
                        },
                        "logo": {
                            "@id": "https://evivermeeren.com/#/schema/person/image/"
                        },
                        "sameAs": [
                            "https://evivermeeren.com"
                        ],
                        "url": "https://evivermeeren.com/author/evivermeeren/"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "_links": {
            "self": [
                {
                    "href": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/2484"
                }
            ],
            "collection": [
                {
                    "href": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts"
                }
            ],
            "about": [
                {
                    "href": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/post"
                }
            ],
            "author": [
                {
                    "embeddable": true,
                    "href": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/1"
                }
            ],
            "replies": [
                {
                    "embeddable": true,
                    "href": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=2484"
                }
            ],
            "version-history": [
                {
                    "count": 10,
                    "href": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/2484/revisions"
                }
            ],
            "predecessor-version": [
                {
                    "id": 2496,
                    "href": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/2484/revisions/2496"
                }
            ],
            "wp:featuredmedia": [
                {
                    "embeddable": true,
                    "href": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/2229"
                }
            ],
            "wp:attachment": [
                {
                    "href": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media?parent=2484"
                }
            ],
            "wp:term": [
                {
                    "taxonomy": "category",
                    "embeddable": true,
                    "href": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?post=2484"
                },
                {
                    "taxonomy": "post_tag",
                    "embeddable": true,
                    "href": "https://evivermeeren.com/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?post=2484"
                }
            ],
            "curies": [
                {
                    "name": "wp",
                    "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                    "templated": true
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: can you share this log : -  **const json = await response.json();**

Comment: Anik Vora, I've put some of the JSON in the post! I think it should be something like item.yoast_head_json.og_image.url, but that doesnt work...